# Receiving request parameters as null for SOAP API in STS

Tags: spring-boot, soap

I'm calling an endpoint from SOAP-UI for a POST request.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:fet="http://www.example.com/fetchMKDataRequest.xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <fet:fetchMKDataRequest>
         <fet:MKDataList>
            <fet:CompanyCode>123</fet:CompanyCode>
            <fet:PersonnelAreaCode>XYZ</fet:PersonnelAreaCode>
         </fet:MKDataList>
      </fet:fetchMKDataRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My endpoint is recognised along with the request body. BUT the value of `MKDataList` appears null as shown below:

[image: Debug mode: request body]

My Endpoint class looks like :

```
@Endpoint
public class FetchMKDataEndpoint {

private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://example.com/fetchMKDataRequest.xsd";
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "fetchMKDataRequest")
@ResponsePayload
public FetchMKDataResponse fetchMKData(@RequestPayload FetchMKDataRequest request) {
    System.out.println("reached FETCHMKDATA endpoint");
    FetchMKDataResponse response = new FetchMKDataResponse();

//commented block of code

    return response;
    }
}
```

Request model is as follows. It was generated using jaxb2-maven-plugin. I had to remove the annotations `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` & `@XmlType` for each class. Also I had to assign `@XmlElement(name = "MKDataList", required = true)`, all such @XmlElements at respective GET methods. Without doing these 2 changes, i was getting `x counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions` exception in SOAP-UI response.

```
 @XmlRootElement(name = "fetchMKDataRequest", namespace="http://www.example.com/fetchMKDataRequest.xsd")
public class FetchMKDataRequest {
    protected List<FetchMKDataRequest.MKDataList> MKDataList;

    @XmlElement(name = "MKDataList", required = true)
    public List<FetchMKDataRequest.MKDataList> getMKDataList() {
        if (MKDataList == null) {
            MKDataList = new ArrayList<FetchMKDataRequest.MKDataList>();
        }
        return this.MKDataList;
    }

    public void setMKDataList(List<FetchMKDataRequest.MKDataList> mKDataList) {
        mKDataList = mKDataList;
    }

    public static class MKDataList implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        protected String companyCode;

        protected String personnelAreaCode;

        @XmlElement(name = "CompanyCode", required = true)
        public String getCompanyCode() {
            return companyCode;
        }

        public void setCompanyCode(String value) {
            this.companyCode = value;
        }

        @XmlElement(name = "PersonnelAreaCode", required = true)
        public String getPersonnelAreaCode() {
            return personnelAreaCode;
        }

        public void setPersonnelAreaCode(String value) {
            this.personnelAreaCode = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anything be done to get MKDataList object in the request body as NOT null?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I made changes in my request model and added package-info.java in the request model package.

Request model class:
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "mkDataList" })
    @XmlRootElement(name = "fetchMKDataRequest", namespace="http://www.example.com/fetchMKDataRequest.xsd")
    public class FetchMKDataRequest  {

```
    @XmlElement(name = "MKDataList", required = true)
    protected List<FetchMKDataRequest.MKDataList> mkDataList;

    public List<FetchMKDataRequest.MKDataList> getMKDataList() {
        if (mkDataList == null) {
            mkDataList = new ArrayList<FetchMKDataRequest.MKDataList>();
        }
        return mkDataList;
    }


    public void setMkDataList(List<FetchMKDataRequest.MKDataList> mkDataList) {
        this.mkDataList = mkDataList;

    }

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "functionalAreaSubGroup",
        "personnelAreaCode"
    })
    public static class MKDataList {

        @XmlElement(name = "FunctionalAreaSubGroup", required = true)
        protected String functionalAreaSubGroup;
        @XmlElement(name = "PersonnelAreaCode", required = true)
        protected String personnelAreaCode;

        public String getFunctionalAreaSubGroup() {
            return functionalAreaSubGroup;
        }
        public void setFunctionalAreaSubGroup(String value) {
            this.functionalAreaSubGroup = value;
        }

        public String getPersonnelAreaCode() {
            return personnelAreaCode;
        }

        public void setPersonnelAreaCode(String value) {
            this.personnelAreaCode = value;
        }
    }
}
```

package-info.java:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.example.com/fetchMKDataRequest.xsd", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.example.model.request;
```

This worked for me. You can define multiple namespaces in 'package-info' class for multiple request/response models.